# AIR 3.3 and android 4.x bugging?

Tags: android, air

My phone is Nexus S which recently got `Android 4.1` and now when developing in `Air 3.3` suddenly `CameraUI` is not working, only getting following error:

```
[ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="ioError" errorID=2038]
```

Anyone able to confirm that, so its not only me having this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

They apparently have a [fix for this](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/air3-5/) in Air 3.5.

This said... I'm experiencing the same issue on a Galaxy S2 with Jelly Beans - but the above update hasn't fixed it :( I'm pretty close to abandoning air as not being able to use cameraUI is a real road block for my application.

Does anyone have cameraUI working on a Android handset running 4.1?